# Is the affine curve $y^2=x^4+y^4$ in $\mathbb A^2$ singular?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

> Is the affine curve $y^2=x^4+y^4$ in $\mathbb A^2$ singular or nonsingular?
>   Find the singularities and show the types of the singularities if the
>   curve is singular.

Let $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4-y^2$.

$f(x,y)=0$ at $(0,0), (0,1), (0,-1)$.

$\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}(x,y)=4x^3=0$ at $(0, y)$.

$\frac{\delta f}{\delta y}(x,y)=4y^3-2y=0$ at $(x, 0), (x, \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$.

The only consistent point in these three equations is $(0,0)$. So does that mean there is one singularity $P_1=(0,0)$? And if so, what 'type' is this singularity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use fooplot and parametric equations to see the graph.

[Graph of $x^4+y^4=y^2$ at http://fooplot.com/plot/4bk34e5n3r](http://fooplot.com/plot/4bk34e5n3r)

**EDIT:** The fooplot graph is not working, so here is an animated GIF

[image: Animated GIF]

Comment: The singularity might be an "osculation" although I believe the term "tacnode" is also used. On the other hand, if it is a true figure 8 the curve might actually be crossing itself, but the tangents are not distinct so it is not a "crunode."  Is that what you mean by "type" of singularity?

Comment: Yeah, the curve is a tacnode: +1. See [Hartshorne](http://www.amazon.com/Algebraic-Geometry-Graduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387902449), Chap.I, Exercise 5.1(a).

Comment: My respects, Professor Wayland.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the location of the one singularity on the curve.

One way to classify the singularity is to [draw the set over $\Bbb R$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E2+%3D+x%5E4+%2B+y%5E4).

If that is not your style, note that the equation may be rewrittten into $x^4 = y^2 - y^4$. Around the origin $y^2$ dominates $y^4$, so the curve looks like $x^4 = y^2$, or $x^2 = |y|$.